# Word problem for finitely presented bounded lattices

Tags: universal-algebra, lattice-theory, word-problem

There is a solution to the word problem for finitely presented (non-bounded) lattices, as well as a solution to the word problem for free bounded lattices. I am assuming that there is a solution to the word problem for finitely presented bounded lattices, but so far I have been unable to find any literature on the topic. So has a solution to this word problem been found?

Comment: You can derive the bounded case from the unbounded case.